# missing tashdeed in othmani script

Tags: quran-recitation, reading-quran, tajweed

I am actually making a transition from the indo-pak script of arabic to the othmani script. In regards to surah ya-seen 36:9, the tashdeed is missing on the letter "wow" (in othmani script). Can someone explain me the rules when it goes missing?

the othmani script version:

> ## سَدًّا وَمِنْ

[image: the othmani script version]

indo-pak version:

> ## سَدًّا وَّمِنْ

[image: indo-pak version]

Scans of the relevant portion can be found: [here](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/AlQuranTarjamaShahRafiUlDeen-ShahRafiUddeenDhelvi#page/n535/mode/2up),
[here](https://archive.org/stream/UrduAndArabicQuranTranslation_201507/urdu%20and%20arabic%20quran%20translation#page/n749/mode/2up),
[here](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/AlQuranTarjamaFaiqUlBayan-ShahRafiUddeenDhelvi#page/n1053/mode/2up),
[here](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/AlQuranTarjamaThanvi-AshrafAliThanvi#page/n571/mode/2up) and
[here](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/TafseeriTarjamaEQuranMajeed-MuhammedRafeeq#page/n837/mode/2up) etc.

Comment: Unfortunaty I can't see neither of the pictures (firewall), but neither the waw واو of "wa ja'alna وجعلنا" nor that "wa min ومن" should have a shiddah in [36:9](http://legacy.quran.com/36/9).

Comment: Are you implying that the shiddah on waw of 'wa min' is wrong ?

Comment: The non image form is mentioned in this edit now

Comment: Yes it looks simply wrong, but could help for the recitation.

Comment: Its not wrong, the pronunciation is the same, the other script simply uses different, more simplistic rules.

Comment: You can refer to audio recitations such as [this](https://youtu.be/lrWLaFecuxo?t=1h59m54s) ,
[this](https://youtu.be/K1qGY5SqAHQ?t=50s) and
[this](https://youtu.be/0iqOLkIs05A?t=1m9s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are identical.

When you have the letter *waw* (و) following a *tanween* (تنوين), the rule is to apply *idgham* (إدغام). *Idgham* in recitation means pronunciation of both that *tanween* with a nasal n sound and the *waw* as separate letters. In the first form ('Uthmani), the *tanween* marks are not vertically aligned (there is a slight angle), which denotes *idgham*. In the second form (Indo-Pak), the *tanween* marks are aligned denoting a full n sound, but since the *waw* has a *shaddah*, then the *n* sound and the *waw* sound become joined in a nasal *n* sound.

Both sound exactly the same.